# How do I make a pagination system with PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, pagination

I have a PHP page that displays my MySQL table's data four rows at a time. If there are, for example, nine rows, the first page would be `http://webste.ca/usedunits.php?page=1` and would display the first four rows. The second page would be `http://webste.ca/usedunits.php?page=2` and would display the fifth to the eigth rows, and the third page would be `http://webste.ca/usedunits.php?page=3` and would display the ninth row.

I am trying to make a link that appears as an arrow that will send the user to `http://webste.ca/usedunits.php?page=2` if they are on `http://webste.ca/usedunits.php?page=1`. If they are on page two there will be a link to page 3, and so on.

I am also trying to make a link that appears as a fast forward button that will send the user to the very last page. My problem is actually making this function.

Here is my full PHP page code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$dbhost = 'dnam';
$dbuser = 'kabm';
$dbpass = 'Kazer';
$dbname = 'kam';
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $connection )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$start_from = ($page-1) * 4; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `used_trailers` ORDER BY `orderid` ASC LIMIT $start_from,4";
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($connection, $sql); 
echo mysqli_error( $connection );
?>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Kelsey Nealon(Kelseynealon@gmail.com), Contract Web Developer" />
<meta name="description" content="GBM Trailer Service Ltd. Calgary-based, proudly serving the tanker and bulk goods transportation industry for over 25 years." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Tanker, Barrel, Parts, Betts, Camloc, Scully, Lubecore, Dixon, GBM, Flotech" />
<title>GBM Trailer Service Ltd. ::: Service</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/mobilemenu.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="responsiveused.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle2 -->
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").click(function () {
            $(".nav-button,.primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
    </script>

    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $('.Default').perfectScrollbar();
      });
    </script>

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45342007-3', 'gbmtrailer.ca');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#102540">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid">
    <div id="navcontain"></div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="mainnaviphone">
    <a href="../index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/gbmlogo.jpg" alt="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo" title="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo"/></a>
    <img src="images/newunitsbutton.png" alt="New Units Button" title="New Units Button" id="buto1">
  <img src="images/usedunitsbutton.png" alt="Used Units Button" title="Used Units Button" id="buto2">
  <a href="../index.html"><img src="images/homebutton.png" alt="home" title="Home" id="homebuto"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/previousbutton.png" alt="previous" title="Previous" id="prevbuto"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/nextbutton.png" alt="next" title="Next" id="nextbuto"/></a>
</div>

<div id="background2">
<div id="textcontrol">

<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
<div id='used1'>
<div id='rigtitle' class="contentHolder Default">
<? echo $row["title"]; ?>
</div>
<table class="infotabe1"><tr><td class="desctde">Description: </td><td rowspan="2" id="content_1" class="infotde contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["description"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Make: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["make"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Model: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["model"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Year: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["year"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Price: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["price"]; ?></td></tr></table>

<!-- Unit Picture -->
<img src='images/<? echo $row["photo"]; ?>' id='mainimage'>
<a href='#'><img src='images/picturesandspecsbutton.png' alt='Pictures and Specs' title='Pictures and Specs' id='picsandspecsbuto'></a>
</div>
<?php 
}; 
?>
</div>
<div id="description" class="resize">
  <p><u>Click</u> or call for more information or enquiries.</p>
</div>
<div id="bottomquote">
  Your Certified Tanker Trailer Specialist
</div>
<div id="bottomcontactinfo">
  <em>Phone <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-4032799717">403 279 9717</a> or <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-888-426-9717">1 888 426 9717</a> 9300 Endeavor Dr. SE, Calgary Alberta, T3S 0A1<br /><a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:info@gbmtrailer.ca">info@gbmtrailer.ca</a>
</div>

<img src="images/visamastercardlogos.gif" id="visamastercardlogos" alt="Visa and Mastercard Logo" title="Visa and Mastercard Logo">

<a href="#"><img id="mycart" src="images/mycart.gif" alt="My Cart" title="My Cart"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
<!--
var autoSizeText;
autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
};

autoSizeText(); // here is where we call the function.
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`orderid`) FROM `used_trailers`";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 4); 

$sqlef = 'SELECT * FROM `used_trailers`';
$rs_resultt = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlef); 
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($rs_resultt);

$record_start = $start_from + 1;
$record_end   = $record_start + 3;

// Remember to check against the max record
if ($record_end > $total_records) {
   $record_end = $total_records;
}

    echo "Showing ".$record_start." - ".$record_end." of ".$rowcount." results ";
    echo "asd<a href='usedunits.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='usedunits.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

Comment: use a php pagination library!

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. What you're doing is called "Pagination". However what you are not doing is actually asking a question.

Comment: You may want to start by not using Title Case in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a link to the last page, you need to know what the last page will be.

The way to do that is to do an additional query to your database asking for the total number of items matching the criterias, and with that and your step (i.e. number of items per page) calculating the number of pages.

In your example that query would be

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `used_trailers`
```

P.S. assuming you put the result of that query in a `$count` variable, the last page (counting from 1) would then be `ceil($count / 4)` (with a corner case for `$count == 0`), 4 being the number of items you show on each page according to your code.

Comment: I used the code `echo "<a href='usedunits.php?page=".$total_pages."'>threearrows</a>";` and it doesn't display the link? I am using 
`$sql = "SELECT COUNT(``orderid``) FROM ``used_trailers``";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 4); ` 
to get `$total_pages`

Comment: `$total_pages` works now! Thanks.